# SQL QUERY - UNION - multiple same tables takes long time

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a big problem with my query to the database.

I explained my problem, I have 11 identical tables (backups). The tables are exactly the same and I need to pull data from them, but it takes a very long time.

I'm using union query like this:

```
select id, name, ... from table_1 WHERE (...)
UNION
select id, name, ... from table_3 WHERE (...)
UNION 
select id, name, ... from table_2 WHERE (...)
... ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

But only query takes about 16 seconds! The database does not have that much data that it took so long ...

```
table_1 = 1.3k
table_2 = 17k
table_3 = 10k
table_4 = 10k 
...     = 10k
table_11= 140K
```

Can you help me to optimize this query? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is probably the order at the end of the complete result. How much data do you get back?

Comment: Avoid using any inner query if you are using. use Join Instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use `UNION` -- unless you want to incur the overhead to remove duplicates.  Instead, use `UNION ALL`:

```
select id, name, ... from table_1 WHERE (...)
UNION ALL
select id, name, ... from table_3 WHERE (...)
UNION ALL
select id, name, ... from table_2 WHERE (...)
...
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

You may also be able to improve performance by using indexes appropriate for the `WHERE` clause.  However, your question does not have enough information for that.

Actually, another optimization is to take the first 50 rows from each subquery *before* the union:

```
(select id, name, ... from table_1 WHERE (...) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(select id, name, ... from table_3 WHERE (...) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(select id, name, ... from table_2 WHERE (...) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 50)
...
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

This reduces the amount of data for the final `ORDER BY`, which should also speed things up.

Comment: Are you still here? I can not use the limits in all queries. I use a paginator and I need all the relevant data. Not just 50 from each table and again i have 11sec to complete query

Comment: @СергейПетров . . . The queries in your question just show a single limit.  The second solution doesn't work for pagination.  But, in fact, if this is something you want to do, you should put all the data in a single table.  This will simplify the query and make it easier to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

UNION tries to sort out all the distinct queries from each table one it has brought them all back. If you know for sure there are no duplicates then you can use UNION ALL instead.

If you're worried about duplicates, use UNION ALL to select everything into a temporary table or subquery, and then GROUP BY every column you are returning to eliminate them.

For a real indication, look in the toolbar for Estimated Execultion Plan. Click this and it will show you what part of the query is taking a long time, and will suggest improvements.